# Error al usar un Sevice, cuando se cierra la Activity que lo llamo

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un servicio que se ejecuta bien, hasta que cierro la Activity que lo llamó o la destruyo en este caso: Activity_llamadas. En el servicio llamo este método:

```
 public void TactivarBroucast(int a,int b) {
        int t=b*3600000+a*1000; 
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.setTime(date);
       c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,t);
       date = c.getTime();
       Timer time = new Timer();
       time.schedule(new Temporisador(), date);
   }
```

Ya en la clase en cargada del Servicio creo un objeto de la clase Activity_llamadas:

```
Activity_llamadas activity_llamadas;
```

en los métodos `onCreate()` y `onStartCommand()`:

```
public void onCreate(){
    activity_llamadas= new Activity_llamadas();
    super.onCreate();
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    Activity_llamadas.getmInstanceActivity().TactivarBroucast(10,0);//valores de a y b. Linea 41 del segundo Logcat 
 return Service.START_STICKY;
} //linea 43 del primer logcat
```

Los métodos `onDestroy()` y `onStart()` solo los tengo declarado no tienen nada adentro.
Me resulta curioso que me pone el clásico "La aplicación se ha detenido" 2 veces y me genera dos Logcat iguales (para mi):
Primer Logcat:

```
03-09 17:01:26.085 14276-14276/com.example.andry.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.andry.myapplication, PID: 14276
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.andry.myapplication.MyService@41dcbad0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2885)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at com.example.andry.myapplication.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:43)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2868)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Segundo Logcat:

```
03-09 17:28:32.980 14451-14451/com.example.andry.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.andry.myapplication, PID: 14451
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.andry.myapplication.MyService@41dceac0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2885)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.andry.myapplication.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:41)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2868)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Decir nuevamente que funciona bien, con la pantalla del teléfono apagada, con la activity en segundo plano, pero al cerrar la app, error.
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Inicializa la clase y llama el método dentro de `onStartCommand()` :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 

    activity_llamadas = new Activity_llamadas();
    activity_llamadas.TactivarBroucast(10,0);//valores de a y b. Linea 41 del segundo Logcat 

 return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Lo siento, me salio el mismo error